# Warning in generation signed apk

Tags: android, apk, build.gradle, build-error

i'm generating the signed apk and having these warnings.
what should i do to solve this ?

```
{
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkUrlFactory
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:there were 17 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `minifyEnabled` set to `true` in your application module, you may wanna add the following line to your `proguard-rules.pro` file as described [here](https://github.com/square/picasso#proguard).

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

Comment: i already doing it. in proguard-project.txt

-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.parse.*{ *; }
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.s**
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: Then add `lintOptions { abortOnError false }` inside `android` in your `build.gradle`

Comment: apk generated succesfully but the generated apk is not installing in any andoird device.

Comment: That is going to be a brand new Stackoverflow question!

Answer (score 0):

Please add the -dontwarn as below in progaurd rules file,

```
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
```